# Fill up A RecyclerView Without Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, gridlayoutmanager

So I have a RecyclerView that uses a GridLayoutManager and uses a super simple adapter that does nothing besides put text in textviews.

My issue is that I want the text to evenly fill out the entire grid (down to the buttons) while making the grid not scrollable. I just want a grid that doesn't scroll and fills up the layout.

Here is what I currently have (the grid is everything between the "you win" and the buttons at the bottom):

[image]

```
val numberOfColumns = 3
                resultsRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns)
                val adapter = GridAdapter(this, gridData)
                resultsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

grid item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I was told this would be a good way of making a grid without doing each textview individually. Is there a better way of making a non-scrollable, evenly spaced grid? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This may sound dumb but why not just make literal textview for each one since you know there is a set amount you want instead of having a list.

Comment: Because that's what I'm trying to avoid. Then you have to keep track of 15 ids and update everyone of them individually and that's very repetitive. Doesn't seem like good practice

Comment: You could put them in an array and run a for loop updating them and sort them.

Comment: Is the number of rows dynamic or static?

Comment: @Matt Wolfe Static.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing linear layout's layout_weight property.

Comment: I did that at first and it just made each row take up the whole screen and it had to scroll

Comment: ok then instead of heights u can use layout_weight attribute. give layout_weight 1 to each item in the list

Comment: I put that in the linear layout and it didn't change anything

Comment: The RecyclerView may/may not scroll based on the screen size unless you explicitly set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` . I wouldn't recommend using a RecylerView if you want to disable scroll regardless of the content size. For specifically your device you can set a minHeight attribute for the grid item as the worst case scenario.

Comment: Then how would you recommend to make a grid like this?

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView has scrolling baked in the widget. If you just need data on the screen consider the ScrollView and add these two lines of code

```
View.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
View.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Then I am guessing just put a bunch of TextViews in the ScrollView to display data

Comment: @Jared Tigard WOW one time resident of Klamath Falls

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to reach for a non-scroll list is:

```
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3) {
     @Override
     public boolean canScrollVertically() {
         return false;
     }
}
```

It's in Java but not hard to port it to Kotlin, hope it helps.